# How can i fetch in php a multiple select that was serialized?

Tags: php, arrays, multi-select

**What i want:**
I'm trying to fetch a multi select inside a php script.

**My problem:** I'm getting only the last value.

I have this form:

```
<form action="create.php" method="post" id="newForm">
```

and inside this form i have some inputs and a **multi select**:

```
<select id="addownerUsers_select" name="addownerUsers_select" class="form-control multiselect-filtering" multiple="multiple" data-fouc>
```

I serialize the form:

```
var data = $("#newForm").serialize();
```

after that i have an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
         type : 'POST',
         url  : 'insert.php',
         data : data,
         dataType: 'json',
```

Now, inside my php:

```
$myvar = @$_POST['addownerUsers_select'];
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` and get rid of the `@`.

Comment: `@$_POST` DON'T! Don't silence error messages

Answer (score -1):

In your name attribute use `name="addownerUsers_select[]"` this way the select values will be stored as a array. In your PHP script treat `$myvar = $_POST['addownerUsers_select'];` as an array.